# Can i block a program using ASM?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, anti-cheat

I am trying for a few days to block a cheat program for my game, i talked with several coders, and one said i can block it using ASM. The program hides very good, i cannot find it in memory, i cannot detect it scanning processes, so maybe this could be the solution? Can someone give me a example how can i detect and block a program with c++ and ASM?

This is my current method to detect and block cheats, using memory dumps:

```
void SystemProcessesScan() 
{
HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if(hProcessSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

        if(Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
        {
            do
            {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                if(hProcess != NULL)
                {
                    if(ScanProcessMemory(hProcess))
                    { 
                        ExitProcess(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            while(Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
}

bool ScanProcessMemory(HANDLE hProcess) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PROCESS_DUMP; i++)
    {
        char aTmpBuffer[MAX_DUMP_SIZE];
        SIZE_T aBytesRead = 0;
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)g_ProcessesDumps[i].m_aOffset, (LPVOID)aTmpBuffer, sizeof(aTmpBuffer), &aBytesRead);

        if(memcmp(aTmpBuffer, g_ProcessesDumps[i].m_aMemDump, MAX_DUMP_SIZE) == 0)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, in other words you have some sort of virus etc.? Don´t try to fix it with some asm, and reinstall everything

Comment: _"and one said i can block it using ASM"_. That's a really vague statement. You should get him or her to elaborate on that.

Comment: Without knowing how it is hiding, how can you tell how to detect it? This is essentially an arms race which you can't win. Look for symptoms server side?

Comment: Yes server side it send some really nasty packets altering my game, but i cannot do anything there. My solution is to detect it in the Client`s folder. There is only 1 version of this cheat wich i cannot block, because you have to select the game executable, then press start, after that the cheat dissappears, but in game it`s there :(

Comment: Learn how the cheat works ( and how cheat programs in general work ), thats the only way you can learn how to prevent that stuff. Just a hint, your description of the one cheat you cannot block, smells to me like simple Dll Injection ( or if theyre brave, pure asm injection ). So you have something to google for. This question is way too broad for SO imho.

Comment: I tried blocking loadlibrary no success... it is using something else :( this is the executable... if someone has about 5 minutes free time: http://www.filedropper.com/muautoclicker

Comment: Looking inside the EXE, I notice the following string: `User-Agent: MUAutoClicker
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` - I'd look in my server-logs to see if anything with that user-agent was hitting my server. If so, just serve junk to anything that's not what you're expecting. Or, even better - send it an "ok" type message yet do nothing or better yet, act maliciously yourself.

Comment: @enhzflep - Well that is the useragent he is using for his website, i notice the cheat makes TCP SEND to aron.icnhost.net, maybe i could block that connection? honestly i don`t know how to block an outgoing connection :|

Comment: @Mr.Mecanik - that sounds like a plan. Perhaps you could install a hook for one/some of the network functions in winsock. Perhaps you could try hooking the `bind` function. Inside your hook, check to see if the requested `s_addr` is `aron.icnhost.net` or it's numerical equivalent. If you hooked a couple of functions, you could tell if `send` was being called on a socket connected to the host you mention. You could then send nothing or a malformed piece of data.. You may find that this article is helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra

Comment: @Mr.Mecanik - actually, just realized that lib hooks the function for use in that program only - the cheat engine would still be unaffected. However, I just noted this gem in the docs for ReadProcessMemory: `The ReadProcessMemory function reads memory in a specified process. The entire area to be read must be accessible, or the operation fails.` - Perhaps you can lock your own memory from outside access. Failing that, this also looks like a good read: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16448/detecting-or-preventing-process-memory-injections-on-windows-anti-hack

Comment: @enhzflep - Thanks for the first idea, i allready have detoured winsock functions, as i intercept the actual connection with my gameserver from the dll, but i don`t see how could i intercept that cheat since i have no idea where it is. But i will try the seconds article! thanks for now, i will come back! :)

Answer (score 1):

The cheat injects a DLL into your game and it sounds like it uses manual mapping to hide the DLL in memory.

The best solution to detect it is to find a sequence of bytes that are unique to this DLL.  Pattern scan your own game processes, if the signature is found, close the game or whatever you want to do at that point.

Search for C++ internal pattern scanning or signature scanning, there are dozens of sources floating around that are uses regularly for this purpose.

Due to it being manually mapped, you must scan all committed memory regions rather than looping through the list of modules.  Use VirtualQuery() in a while loop starting with address 0 until it fails.

Comment: You do realize that first 64 K of address space on Windows are inaccessible?